# read 2-D binary data in Python and write in NetCDF format

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf

I have binary data with following header information:

```
DSET ../prcp/cmorph_test
OPTIONS template little_endian
UNDEF  -999.0
TITLE  Precipitation estimates
XDEF 1440 LINEAR    0.125  0.25
YDEF  480 LINEAR  -59.875  0.25
ZDEF   01 LEVELS 1
TDEF 999999 LINEAR  00z01jan2014  3hr
VARS 1
cmorph   1   99 RAW CMORPH integrated satellite precipitation estimates [mm/3hr]
ENDVARS
```

Please suggest if it is possible to read (and any sample code snippet would be really helpful) and convert it into NetCDF using Python?

Comment: Like this? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html

Comment: You may want, Ibe, to **read whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE** ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with the read of the binary data, but you can read/write netcdf files with:
https://github.com/unidata/netcdf4-python

Answer (score 0):

The Nasa guys don't seem to respond any emails.

It downloads the data and plots it to compare what can be found in
ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/global_CMORPH/3-hourly_025deg/cmorph-precip_3hrly-025deg.gif

```
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import bz2
import urllib.request as request
from contextlib import closing
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_closest_file_index(hour=None, dataHours=np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24])):
    """
    hour is in decimal format: that is 7:40 am is 7.66666
    assuming here we have 8 data files/ 24h == 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21
    (24 is with to get datapoints from the next 24h period)
    """
    return (np.argmin(np.abs(float(hour)-dataHours)))

def cmorph_download(year=None, month=None, day=None, hour=None,
                    urlStart='ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CMORPH_V1.0/CRT/0.25deg-3HLY/',
                    ext='.bz2'):
    """
    Returns rain-rate in single grid, first dimension is lat, second lon
    first data is from data[lat=-59.875, lon=0.125] , step is 0.25

    download cmorph water data from
    ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CMORPH_V1.0/CRT/0.25deg-3HLY/

    data is real*4 little endian binary

    ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CMORPH_V1.0/CTL/CMORPH_V1.0_CRT_0.25deg-3HLY.ctl
    There it says:
    OPTIONS template little_endian
    UNDEF  -999.0
    TITLE  Precipitation estimates
    XDEF 1440 LINEAR    0.125  step 0.25 last is 359.875
    YDEF  480 LINEAR   59.875  step 0.25 last is -59.875
    ZDEF   01 LEVELS 1

    motivation:
  
    The CMORPH technique provides a passive
    microwave (PMW) rain-rate dataset that is derived from
    low-Earth-orbit microwave satellite observations, and
    these observations are translated via spatial propagation
    information obtained from geostationary IR1 data.
    """
    fileNumber = get_closest_file_index(hour=hour)
    if fileNumber == 8:
        # data is from the next day...
        # so we take it next day at 0am
        fileNumber = 0
        minute = round((float(hour) - int(hour)) * 60.)
        dataDate = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute))
        year = dataDate.year
        month = dataDate.month
        day = dataDate.day
    print("fileNumber:", fileNumber)
    file = 'CMORPH_V1.0_ADJ_0.25deg-3HLY_' \
           + str(year) + str(month).rjust(2,'0') + str(day).rjust(2,'0') \
           + ext

    ftppath = urlStart \
              + '/' + str(year) \
              + '/' + str(year) + str(month).rjust(2,'0') \
              + '/' + file


    fileName = file
    if not os.path.exists(fileName):
        with closing(request.urlopen(ftppath)) as r:
            print(f"Downloading... {ftppath}")
            with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
    else:
        print("using old file:", fileName)

    with bz2.open(fileName, "rb") as f:
        # Decompress data from file
        data = f.read()
    data = np.fromstring(data, dtype='<f4')
    data = np.reshape(data, (8, (120 * 4), (360 * 4)))
    data = data[fileNumber, ...]
    data = np.squeeze(data)

    return data

data = cmorph_download(year=2012, month=3, day=19, hour=3)
# to compare with
# ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/global_CMORPH/3-hourly_025deg/cmorph-precip_3hrly-025deg.gif
plt.contour(data)
plt.show()
```